# Как поключиться к RMAN в Java?

Tags: oracle, java

Хочу сделать визуальный RMAN! Обычным подключением в Джаве не получается выполнять скрипты RMAN-а, поэтому хочу спросить можно ли это сделать на прямую и как отправлять запросы и получать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JDBC с RMAN не работает. Используйте для запуска комманд класс java.lang.Runtime

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command");
```

Answer (score 2):

Я не слышал о каком-либо интерфейсе работы с RMAN из Java напрямую, и, честно говоря, думаю, что его нет. Поэтому я бы попробовал сделать так:

- оболочку написать на Java (или чем-то другом, что удобно);
- основные задачи вынести в файлы сценариев RMAN;
- из оболочки цеплять RMAN с нужными сценариями.